# Publishing program on VB.Net 2010 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, deployment, vb.net-2010, publishing

I am trying to publish my program implemented using VB.Net 2010 Ultimate and the database is MS Access 2007 (.accdb), in my code, the path of the database was in the debug folder.

What I want to happen is that when I publish my program and other people download it, they can use the program properly.

I tried this and one of my friends told me there's an unhandled exception because the path of the database was invalid.

Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to publish my application?

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally if you have a file in the bin/ debug folder whilst developing you can refer to it with the My.application startuppath notation, so when it comes to deploying your application that file would end up being placed in the program's main directory.

However if you want your end users to be able to write to that file (and it's pretty much a given that you would with a database) then you will need to consider permissions carefully when it comes to deploying your application.  Consequently you might want to consider deploying the mdb file to a seperate folder that is publically accessible for all users (all users application data or all users documents spring to mind as good examples).